# Combining generic MVP pattern with abstract factory pattern

Tags: generics, mvp, abstract-factory

Is there some way to solve my code below? I'm kinda stuck.
How can I use a factory to create generic presenters, is it even possible without a non generic base class?

```
public abstract class Presenter<T>
{}

public SomePresenter : Presenter<ISomeVew>
{}

public SomeOtherPresenter : Presenter<ISomeOtherView>
{}

public class Factory()
{

  public ??? CreatePresneter(int runTimeValue)
  {
    if (runTimeValue == 1)
      return new SomePresenter()
    else
      return new SomeOtherPresenter()  
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many times generic base classes need non-generic bases, so write

```
public abstract class Presenter
{}

public abstract class PresenterOf<T> : Presenter
{}
```

and use `PresenterOf` for your presenters.

Then `CreatePresenter` can return `Presenter`.  Obviously, this only helps if `ISomeView` and `ISomeOtherView` have a base class that Presenter can work on.

If these views and presenters don't have commonality in the interface, then using one factory to make them all might not make sense.